# Symfony delopyment on Cluster with cache/logs and ACL

Tags: php, symfony

We have a cluster with two nginx-servers running our Symfony3 application. Both servers are connected to a NFS storage providing the cluster-configuration for nginx and php-fpm and also containing the application-code.

Problem: As we had permission-issues with cache on NFS we found out, that Symfony recommends to **NOT** host cache and logs on NFS share regarding performance issues.

Solution: Based on that and since our NFS version does not support ACL we have moved the cache and logs to directories which are directly on the servers. We achieved this by modifying the AppKernel. Following this we have configured ACL on both servers for the directories.

In general we are searching for a "better solution" which does not require to adjust deployment-configuration each time a new server is added.

Comment: Why do you share the application on an NFS disk? Why don't you make an application instance by server and use the regular cache and logs folders? (I really don't know if this is better, just asking by curiosity)

Comment: We have thought about that but it would be easier to just maintain one "instance". Let's say for example we deploy on ever node - deployment is succesful on node1 and fails on node2. We don't have the possibility to revert node1 to version of node2 - and also we can't just exclude node2 because of performance.

Comment: I understand, but a cluster is also meant to respond to deployments fails. If your deployment fails on the only node you have, then the entire app will be down. Am I wrong?

Comment: Its deployed on a NFS share which is multi-redundant so this has maximum security to avoid downtimes.

Comment: I see, thanks for taking the time to explain it to me!